# Is there a way to prevent typing lowercase with both capslock engaged and shift depressed?

Tags: linux, keyboard, capslock

We all know the drill: we forget that Capslock is on, then start a new sENTECE. Is there a way, in Linux (either console or X) to actually prevent the combination of Caps Lock and Shift from producing lowercase at all? For example, by a combination of options in /etc/keyboard or other tweaks?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried regarding this issue so far?

Answer (score 0):

I quote the accepted
[answer by Mauricio](https://askubuntu.com/a/1273412/963426)
using gnome from the post
[How to toggle off Caps Lock by Shift key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562020/how-to-toggle-off-caps-lock-by-shift-key)

Other answers in the post refer to other flavors of Linux.

> First install gnome-tweak-tool by using this command:
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
> ```
>
> Now open 'Tweaks' application, then go to : Keyboard & Mouse →
> Keyboard → Additional Layout Options → Miscellaneous compatibility
> options → check '**Shift cancels Caps Lock**'. Close window.
>
> Works fine in **Ubuntu 20.04.**
>
> [image: 'Additional Layout Options' screenshot]
>
> ---
>
> Update for **Ubuntu 22.04:**
>
> First install gnome-tweaks by using this command (thanks @Paul P)
>
> ```
> $ apt-get install gnome-tweaks
> ```
>
> Then open "Tweaks", find option within Keyboard & Mouse → Keyboard →
> Additional Layout Options → Compatibility options → and check '**Both
> Shift together enable Caps Lock; one Shift key disables it.**'.